# What's the effect of per site meta's reputation system on the activity?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta

Since the split of MSO/MSE I noticed that the reputation on MSO does not change according to activity on MSO. This is all by design and okay for me.

But then I wondered, how does this impact the behavior of users on MSO? Are they more or less likely to post questions or answers? Or do most of them think:

> I don't care for the badges, so I will spend my time on the main site where I can gain rep.

Of course, this question until now belongs on MSO itself, but I think we, as fresh child meta, can learn a lot from you guys having your own meta for a much longer time.

So my questions:

1. Does the non-rep system on child metas affects users activity?
2. Does the community benefit from this or not?

Comment: Gut feeling time: from the fresh participation on MSO and some of the comments posted, I gather that there is at least less of a fear to participate.

Comment: @Bart: that is what I thought too. But what is the incentive of people coming to MSO now? 'Just to ask questions', and a few that usually answer them. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: The incentive for OPs is simple: they have encountered a problem and want support (in whatever form that might come). And then there are those in the community with an interest in the community as a whole. And they'll get the satisfaction that they've been able to just help. At least, that does it for me.

Comment: @Bart: But aren't there to less of them really wanting to help?

Comment: I can't speak for other child metas. And this case is a bit of an outlier because a large part of the old MSO community just continued in the new one. It didn't have a new start in that sense. But not everything requires rep. I have what now, 47k here on MSE? I like the privileges (and miss them on MSO) but apart from that I couldn't care.

Comment: @Bart: I feel more connected to MSE then MSO. MSO seems to become a 'Why can't I ask questions any more?' meta. That's why I wondered if non-SO users experience this in there metas.

Comment: Then you haven't been around on MSE (old-MSO) for very long. We had those all the time and nuked plenty of them. It's not something MSO is becoming. Nothing new. I just can't help nuke them until I get a bit more rep. :)

Comment: @Bart: Have been there on MSE when that was the problem. MSE is much more cleaner now, but now I feel like the fun part is taken out of MSO.